# Database is not connecting

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect database.
Here's the details of my work:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
mysql_select_db("employees",$con);
if(!$con)
{
die("cant establish database connection".mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo "connection Created";
```

where in xamp my database,which i created in phpmyadmin in localhost xamp, is on the following directory:

```
 C:\xampp\mysql\data
```

Here a folder named Employees is created then it has some files in it.
when i run php file to create connection it shows nothing on the screen according to my code it must show :

```
  connection created
```

now can anyone tell me where im wrong? why its not showing any output?

Comment: Do not use the deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_`or `PDO`with prepared statement

Comment: It is crazy. where it shows `connection created`? You echoing `connection successfull`

Comment: @Jens i used mysqli_ but it still not working?

Answer (score 3):

If that's your whole script, you're missing a closing brace at the end `}`.

Turn on error display, it will be useful in the future: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Also have a read of this: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: '}' it is there just in copying somehow i missed,
and can u tell me about every other things am I doing good or not?

Comment: You should check if the connection succeeded before you select the database. Everything else is in the links above.